# Server-side Application to registration ID for Android device

Tags: android

I am working on an application for android to get the Device Id from the respective devices of client.

I am following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

Here I am struck at the point where I need to make the server-side application to get device Id from GCM.

Actually, I am not an Android programmer and I have no knowledge of this platform, I just want to generate device id that is further required in the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-protips-advanced-topics-for-expert-android-app-developers.html you should generate a unique installation ID, which can be done via UUID:

```
String installationID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

After generation of the installationID, you can save the ID in the SharedPreferences.